# Is browser cache essentially a key/value store with the key the server path of the object and the value the requested object?

Tags: javascript, caching, browser

I'm just wondering if I preload a file in javascript with an async/await fetch, then later in the code I submit a request to fetch that file again...will any http requests to that path return from the browser cache first?

This would essentially make the browser cache a key/value cache with the key being the server side path and the value being the file.

Any caveats I should be aware of?

Comment: The cache is not part of JavaScript. It's part of the runtime environment, e.g. the browser cache.

Comment: Edited my post to make that clearer!  Thanks! 

Is that essentially a k/v store with the key being the path?  
Just to build my mental model about it?